# NetLogo BehaviorSpace - Measure runs using reporters

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

In my NetLogo model my turtles are called inhabitants. each inhabitant has their own start opinion (initial_opinion) an a final opinion (final_opinion). Their opinion are calculated using random numbers so i want to run the model atleast 20 times when i change some parameters. Therefore i'm using the BehaviorSpace.

However, i have no idea how i get my values of these two variables in a spreadsheet. What code do i need to add in the box 'Measure runs using these reporters:'. I do not want to count my turtles since the number stays the same, and other commands I tried did not work. Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 2):

I use something along these lines

```
[(list who inital_option final_opinion)] of inhabitants
```

the spreadsheet will be assorted but that is easy to fix in post.

Comment: This does not work for me. In my model I have 3 producers and after each run, they each have 5 values regarding the profit of 5 vehicles they manufactured. When I use this `[(list who profit)] of producers` , I run into the error saying that "reoprter for measuring a run fails to report - NULL". How can I resolve this issue? Thanks