# Netlogo - BehaviorSpace - reporter for measuring runs failed to report a result

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

In my model, I have 3 producers and after each run, they each have 2 values for the profit and sale earned from their vehicle sold in the market. The model needs to run 100 times. I followed the steps for the behaviorspace tool, but I was uncertain what to add for the "Measure runs using reporters" section. I found this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875056/netlogo-behaviorspace-measure-runs-using-reporters) . Following that, I used this

`[(list who profit)] of producers [(list who sale)] of producers` in order to see the number for "who" and the corresponding profit and sale. This has an error saying that `"reporter for measuring a run fails to report result - NULL"`. How can I resolve this issue? I should also mention that in the code there is no to-report without a return, but the returned things are not what I want to collect.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can you include your `breed` and breed-specific variable declarations? Your reporter syntax works for me, as long as it's on two lines in the `Measure runs using these reporters` field.

Also, you can simplify your output to a single reporter, if you want- using this toy setup as a test:

```
breed [ producers producer ]
producers-own [ profit sale ]

to setup
  ca
  create-producers 3 
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask producers [
    set profit profit + random 50
    set sale sale + random 5
  ]
end
```

And a BehaviorSpace experiment that looks like:

[image]

Your output (with the 'Table' option) should look like:

[image]

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for making it extremely clear. Yes. I had 2 mistakes. One was having `repetition = 1` and `steps = 100`. I also had 4 parallel runs which should be changed to 1 to get the result the way you illustrated. It works with no error now. I am just confused about `"step"`. what is it exactly? Assuming it is the seconds for each run, I left to be zero and set a condition `ticks = 50` to stop. Now in the result, for each "run number" there are two outputs one with `step = 0` and the other with `step = 1` . Why is it like that?

Comment: @user710 - No problem! For speed, you may want to allow the default parallel runs- it will let NetLogo use all cores available to run multiple simulations in parallel. Step just refers to the number of times the `Go` commands were called- you can see that I set my time limit to 10 and set it to *not* `Measure runs at every step`, so the `[step]` output values for every run in my Excel file is 10. I'd guess that you have that "Measure runs..." box ticked so that you see step 0, step 1, etc.